# How to keep an inherited property of a child class from serializing

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a base class that a number of other classes inherit from.  The base class supports XML serialization and has a property that is serializaed.

I would like to keep that same property from serializing in one of the child classes.  Is this possible?  How do I do it?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: Only in one child class and what about other child classes?

Comment: Only in the one child class, at least at this time. I want it serialized in the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `XmlIgnoreAttribute`. See this article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx

Comment: The property is defined in a base class where I want it to be serialized normally.  I can't decorate it with the `XmlIgnoreAttribute` there.

Comment: You can set the XMLIgnoreAttribute in the base class and then selectively override them in the derived classes. This article describes overriding XML serialization attributes.  http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2010/05/selectively-overriding-xml.html

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the property you want to hide with the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Customer")]
public class SimplifiedCustomer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```